# Output cache not working for AJAX varyByParam

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, caching

I have an endpoint for a WCF web service which is not getting output cache hits in the performance monitor for AJAX requests, it does get an output cache for **non** AJAX requests to endpoint.

**Web config:**

```
<caching>
  <outputCacheSettings >
    <outputCacheProfiles>
      <add location="Any" name="myCache" duration="3600" varyByParam="*" />
     </outputCacheProfiles>
  </outputCacheSettings>
</caching>
```

Is there an option I'm missing in the config? I've not included Javascript because I doubt the problem lies there since the server shouldn't have to check any headers to determine cache worthiness.

The endpoint:

```
[AspNetCacheProfileAttribute("myCache")]
        [WebGet(ResponseFormat= WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "suburb?name={name}&state={state}&category={category}&bedrooms={bedrooms}&country={country}")]
```

Comment: Can you post the Javascript as well? I've just tried recreating this to see if not explicitly enabling the output caching line might have an effect but to no avail, and can only get the behaviour you're seeing with JS modifications.

Answer (score 1):

When you make an ajax call , it is possible that, you are passing it as cache: false.

When you call like that, ajax call will pass the URL with an extra parameter and value will be  a random unique number. Since asp.net method receive this extra parameter and you configure outputcache with **varyByParam="*"** , this method will never cache. The solutions are

1. set **cache: true** in ajax call - (not good when you are calling a dynamic method ) or
2. set outputcache
       **varyByParam="none"** (use only when your method need cache irrespective of parameters) or
3. set outputcache
       **varyByParam="parameter1;parameter2"** (this is the ideal solution if you have multiple parameters) . For single parameter use
   **varyByParam="parameter1"**

Sorry for the late reply. I saw this question just now.